# Is it possible to express $f(x) = \frac{C_1a_1^x+C_2a_2^x}{C_3a_3^x+C_4a_4^x}$ in the form $ce^{dx}$?

Tags: exponential-function, problem-solving

A problem I have gives a function of the form $$f(x) = \frac{C_1a_1^x+C_2a_2^x}{C_3a_3^x+C_4a_4^x}$$
where $a_i$ and $C_i$ are real constants. When I play around with it and plot it for various random values of $a_i$ and $C_i$ and most of the time it fits the exponential function of the form $ce^{dx}$ spot on (i.e. $R^2=1$ in a least squares regression).

> Is there a way to express $f(x)$ as $ce^{dx}$ where $c$ and $d$ depends on $a_i$ and $C_i$?

I have tried the tricks I know but none of them seem to work.

Comment: You can't express $f(x)$ as $ce^{dx}$, because it isn't. The right word is "approximate".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To express $f(x)$ as $ce^{dx}$, usually no.  To approximate it, often yes.  For example, for large $x$, look at the four exponentials, and the bigger ones win.

For example,
$$
\frac{5\;2^x - 6\;4^x}{2^x + 3\;3^x} \sim -2\;\left(\frac43\right)^x\quad \text{as } x \to \infty
$$
which we do by noting $4^x$ defeats $2^x$ in the numerator, and $3^x$ defeats $2^x$ in the denominator:
$$
\frac{5\;2^x - 6\;4^x}{2^x + 3\;3^x} =
\frac{5\;(2/3)^x - 6\;(4/3)^x}{(2/3)^x + 3\;(3/3)^x}
\sim \frac{0-6\;(4/3)^x}{0+3} = -2\;\left(\frac43\right)^x
$$

Comment: Thank you. I guess the absurdly good regression-fit confused me.